# How to prepare Ubuntu 14.04 for installing Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I came across a tutorial which lists a number of libraries to install before installing Django (I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Python3, and Django 1.8):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev python3.4-dev python-software-properties libpq-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

But other tutorials may not list so many libraries to install. I wonder which are absolutely necessary, and others may be omitted?

Comment: In case you're not aware, any Ubuntu/Debian package beginning with `python` is for Python 2, while Python 3-specific packages begin with `python3`. So, several of those packages are pointless. Additionally, given the lag between the release of a new module version, and the update of the Ubuntu/Debian package, it's generally a good idea to use `pip` for as much of your package management as possible, and leave `apt-get` for those modules you have an extremely difficult time compiling from source.

Comment: Yes, you are right and that's why I would like to clear up what are necessary and without conflict (I am not familiar with those libraries). According to Thane's answer below, I only have to run 2 commands to prepare for Django installation!

Comment: If you're just going to be using Django for basic stuff, and won't be manipulating images or anything, then `Pillow` or anything else is not needed - `sudo pip3 install django` will work just fine. If you're going to be using sqlite as your database, you won't even need to set up a database adaptor, as it's built-in to Python. Of course, if/once you put your app into production, you'll need a real DB, like Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, or whatever, but it's not necessary for just learning the framework. Check out http://djangoproject.com - they have tons of info there, and the tutorial is excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to install these dependencies if you want image processing via `pillow` and if you plan on installing it via `pip` (the Python package manager) rather than `apt-get` (Ubuntu's package manager).

Since you're using a virtualenv, you will need to install this package from source. The following commands will get the build dependencies and install `pillow` using `pip`.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python3-imaging
$ pip install pillow
```

Note that pillow is a beast to compile. Be prepared to wait several minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thane. So you're saying that nothing in the installation list is necessary and all I have to do is to install with `pip3 install python3-imaging` (or `pip3 install Pillow` instead)? That would be a good news.

Comment: You need to do those steps if you `pip3 install pillow` because these steps are setting up the build dependencies for that package.

Comment: If you're not using a virtualenv, I'd highly recommend just using the system version through `apt-get` (for `pillow` at least).

Comment: The virtualenv will be used.

Comment: So, only one **system** installation command is enough, and all others will happen in the virtual environment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75615/discussion-between-thane-brimhall-and-yltang52).